# Angular 2+ - cleaner html without additional tags for component elements

Tags: angular

Is there a way to avoid the tags generated for components so that my output will be clean and easy to style?

I am trying to convert a bootstrap template to angular components but found that for each component there is additional tag generated.

Here is the html i got in the template

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="component">
     ------
     ------
   </div>
</div>
```

After I converted the #component as an Angular Component my resultant html is

```
<div id="container">
  <app-component>
      <div id="component">
       -------------
       -------------
      </div>
  </app-component>
</div>
```

Here i am trying to find if there is a way to avoid the  so that i don't have to adjust the styling after moving the html components.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your AppComponent let say, you can ignore adding the `div` with `id="component" and in the parent component, you can assign the id directly to your child component.

```
<div id="container">
  <app-component id="component">
       -------------
       -------------
  </app-component>
</div>
```

If you want to add more styles to the container of the child component in it's css file you can do it like so:

```
:host {
 width: 100%;
}
```

I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

i thing you can omit extra div's instead, because your component it is a container

```
<app-container>
  <app-component>

  </app-component >
</app-container>
```

and you can use :host {} for component styling or class in usual way

in container.scss

```
:host {
  background-color: green;
}
```

in component.scss

```
:host {
  background-color: indigo;
}
```